# What is pp-number C++

Tags: c++

Run into such term as "pp-number", can't [google](http://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=pp-number+C%2B%2B&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) what exactly it is, help please.

Comment: It took about 5 seconds of Googling: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/63522-preprocessing-numbers

Comment: The OP has already seen that topic (stated so in previously deleted comments to this question).

Comment: *"Run into term"* - it may help if you give a little more context. Where did you see this term?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *preprocessing number* is a sequence of digits and other characters which make up an integer or floating literal. For example `42` or `1.5e-7`.

Answer (score 4):

Preprocessing numbers:

#### 2.9 Preprocessing numbers [lex.ppnumber]

> `pp-number:`
> `digit`
> `. digit`
> `pp-number digit`
> `pp-number nondigit`
> `pp-number e sign`
> `pp-number E sign`
> `pp-number .`

Comment: Can you explain in some words what is that?..

Comment: @ManInTheHood see - http://www.mers.byu.edu/docs/standardC/preproc.html, but now it should be easier to google.

Answer (score 2):

A PP-number is a number that is at the same time:

1. A palindrome in decimal notation.
2. A prime number.

These are sometimes used for programming exercises, tests or contests.

Comment: The question was vague enough to not be sure if he was talking about low level, under the hood C++ concepts or if he's just going through some programming book where an exercise was about prime palindrome numbers.